# flutter json object to to list for dropdown menu

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I got json object from API and i have to show this as a dropdown.

> Json response

```
{
    "deliveryCharges": {
        "_id": "607b156404fb0a0184db98fe",
        "businessId": "607b14ef04fb0a0184db98e3",
        "createdAt": "2021-04-17T17:05:40.546Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-04-18T10:16:13.633Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "deliveryZones": {
            "Bangladesh": {   // country dropdown item 1
                "Mirpur": {.  // city dropdown item 1
                    "deliveryCost": "50",
                    "status": true
                }
            },
            "American Samoa": { // country dropdown item 2
                "lost city": {  // city dropdown item 2
                    "deliveryCost": "50",
                    "status": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

> Here **Bangladesh** and **American Samoa** in country drop down

> Here **Mirpur** and **lost city** in city drop down

I thing i have to change json object to array. But did not found good example.

Advanced thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since

```
"deliveryZones": {
            "Bangladesh": {   // country dropdown item 1
                "Mirpur": {.  // city dropdown item 1
                    "deliveryCost": "50",
                    "status": true
                }
            },
            "American Samoa": { // country dropdown item 2
                "lost city": {  // city dropdown item 2
                    "deliveryCost": "50",
                    "status": true
                }
            }
        }
```

this object will be stored in Map Data structure
you can convert map keys to list

```
map.keys.toList()
```

Answer (score 1):

> First, declare two variables of an array.

```
List<String> countryList = [];
List<String> zoneList = [];
```

> After that parse JSON data which is provided from API response.

```
Map<String, dynamic> decoded = json.decode(response);
for (var colour in decoded.keys) {
    List<String>.from(decoded[colour]['deliveryZones'].keys.map((model) {
        countryList.add(model);
    }));

    List<String>.from(decoded[colour]['deliveryZones']['Bangladesh'].keys.map((model) {
        zoneList.add(model);
    }));
}
```

> Now print and show the output

```
print("country $countryList");
print("zoneList $zoneList");
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have Created a sample Example Based on the json that you provided.

json you provided :

```
{
  "deliveryCharges": {
      "_id": "607b156404fb0a0184db98fe",
      "businessId": "607b14ef04fb0a0184db98e3",
      "createdAt": "2021-04-17T17:05:40.546Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-04-18T10:16:13.633Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "deliveryZones": {
          "Bangladesh": {  
              "Mirpur": {
                  "deliveryCost": "50",
                  "status": true
              }
          },
          "American Samoa": { 
              "lost city": {  
                  "deliveryCost": "50",
                  "status": true
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Based on the json I have Made an Example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _isLoading = false;

  String countryValue;
  List<String> countriesList = [];
  List<String> cityList = [];
  String cityValue;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");

    var item = json.decode(data);

    item.forEach((key, value) {
      print(value["deliveryZones"]);
      value["deliveryZones"].forEach((key, value) {
        print(key);
        countriesList.add(key);
        value.forEach((key, value) {
          print(key);
          cityList.add(key);
        });
      });
    });

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Users List "),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: 300,
          child: _isLoading
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        hint: Text(
                            'Choose Country'), // Not necessary for Option 1
                        value: countryValue,
                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            countryValue = newValue;
                          });
                          print(countryValue);
                        },
                        items: countriesList.map((String company) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(company),
                            value: company,
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        hint: Text('Choose City'), // Not necessary for Option 1
                        value: cityValue,
                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            cityValue = newValue;
                          });
                          print(cityValue);
                        },
                        items: cityList.map((String company) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(company),
                            value: company,
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works.